# thumb becomes yellow on progress change in android seekbar, how to prevent this?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, seekbar

I have a seekbar View in my android app.

Whenever the user change the progress, the thumb becomes yellow.

How can I prevent this and leave it gray as originally was?

can I leave the native image while preventing it from turning yellow on press?

Answer (score 0):

Use Drawable/Image to Thumb Like:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/yourDrawable"
```

**It will resolve your problem**

Comment: thanks, but can I leave the native image while preventing it from turning yellow on press?